# Xamarin app exit, but still in Task Manager

Tags: android, exit

I need to implement an ***app exit*** when the user hits the device's back button.
My code makes the app to quit, but when opening the task manager by hitting the menu button twice, my app is still in there. When I click on it, it restarts from the splashscreen...

**I've tried :**

`Finish()`

*Or*

`FinishAffinity();`

followed by :

```
Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
```

*Or*

```
Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);
```

It doesnt remove my app from the task manager.

PS: By task manager I mean the page where you can see all opened apps, and you can quit them by swipping your finger.

Comment: The recent app selector is not a running process list.

Comment: That's what I guessed, but when I open Google Chrome, and I close it by pressing back button, it does'nt appear anymore in the app selector